# How can I authenticate against ADFS by passing login info as Request headers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, adfs

We have a mobile app that wants to access a view on our ASP.NET MVC4 website. In order to do so, the app needs to authenticate by different means than our ADFS login process. The mobile app makes a request to the service and passes in the username and password as Request headers. In the ASP.NET application `global.asax` file, we have the following:

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers[Mobile.Configuration.iPadUsername];
        string password = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers[Mobile.Configuration.iPadPassword];
        string acctID = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers[Mobile.Configuration.iPadAcctStr];

        //bypass adfs
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username)
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password)
            && !HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            //web service call to authenticate the user

            if (success)
            {
                var genIden = new GenericIdentity(usrnm);
                var genClaim = new GenericPrincipal(genIden, new string[] { });
                HttpContext.Current.User = genClaim;
                var token = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.CreateSessionSecurityToken(genClaim, "test mobile", DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1), true);
                FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.AuthenticateSessionSecurityToken(token, true);


                Response.Clear();

                Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";

                Response.AddHeader("Location", "/Default/IndexRedirectFromMobile");

                Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```

What ends up happening is when setting the user to the `GeneralPrincipal` above, we have `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated` set to `true`. However, after we try to redirect the user to the correct landing page, the request is no longer authenticated and they get caught in an infinite loop.

What can we do to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

A simplest way would be to write the token to a cookie

```
var token = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.CreateSessionSecurityToken(genClaim, "test mobile", DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1), true);

FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessonTokenToCookie( token );
```

You need to remember that the client must support cookies. Depending on the actual client technology you use, this can be easier or harder.

However, you don't need to use the SAM module to retain the session. You can use Forms Authentication, a custom authentication header or anything else.